# Bootstrap 3 container within container-fluid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am re-coding an opencart theme but this time using bootstrap 3. Is it the correct / recommended way to place bootstrap `container` within a `container-fluid` to have a central container. If not which would be a more correct to achieve this.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container-fluid">
<div id="container">
 <div class="row"> 
  <?php if ($logo) { ?>

 <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div id="logo"><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></a></div>
  <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div id="pringle"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/pringle.png" /></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div><!-- Static Header Ends-->
```

[image: Bootstrap container within container-fluid]

Comment: This isn't good practice to do this, you should stick to using ether container or container-fluid. If you want something like your photo look at bootstrap columns offset feature

Comment: @TomTucka Explain why this would not be a good practice? It does not break anything or add anything but an extra padding to its sides, and is completely valid.

Comment: @ProDexorite I was just always told not to by my mentor

Comment: @TomTucka That is weird. It is basically the same when you put an extra row with columns inside another column. Padding is just about the only thing that comes as "extra" and is the easiest and recommended way on dividing content.

On this situation though, if some content were to be added inside the `.container-fluid` itself, on the sides of the `.container`, I would not recommend it. As long as the content itself goes to `.container` this is the best practice to grant you access to that space of the page's background.

Comment: @ProDexorite Thanks! Every day is a school day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**

`.container` can be used with `.container-fluid` to give you better possibilities on styling your header's background.

Since the fluid container itself does not have much styling on it, **you can use it to divide different parts of the page vertically**. Adding an extra class or an ID to it gives you a bit of freedom when it comes to applying CSS-styling on it.

It should not cause any issues except when you go to mobile view, you should maybe tick off the padding from `.container-fluid` if you want to fill the page's width with your header.

Answer (score -1):

Why does the container have to be inside the container-fluid?

Could you make the container a container-fluid and give it a margin? Or make them both container-fluid?

Comment: This should rather be a comment than an answer, as you're not actually giving any answers here.